# ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I am working with a column named "Time". This has hours in military time format, each row represents an hour. The goal is to convert each row into a datetime hours, however  I keep running into this Value Error. I have tried using strip to no success.
Below I have listed all the values in the column, the code to convert into datetime and the error. Let me know if I should show my strip code, I am very new so maybe I screwed that up.

```
array(['21', '10', '15', '13', '12', '08', '20', '02', '19', '11', '00',
       '03', '18', '17', '06', '05', '23', '01', '22', '14', '09', '16',
       '04', '07', '24'], dtype=object)

df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format= '%H')

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4
```

Comment: `%H` is used for Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.ie, `00, 01, …, 23`. So it seems like the array has `24`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.