# strptime unconverted data remains

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, strptime

I have a string I want to convert to a datetime in the following format:

```
'31-12-2022:24'
```

The last two digits being the hour. I tried the following to convert it:

```
dt = datetime.strptime(z[1], '%d-%m-%Y:%H').date()
```

But get the following error:

```
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 4
```

Why is it only selecting the first digit? I have a workaround, splitting the string and converting them separately before rejoining them but I'd like to just do it in one line.

What I would ideally like is a datetime object that allows me to do some maths on the difference between two dates (edit* and times), which I assume is easiest in datetime format?

Comment: Hour cannot be `24`: [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.hour). Use a string split since you only care about the date anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052483/valueerror-unconverted-data-remains-4

Comment: Question edited, my mistake, I care about the hour too. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split values and hours convert to timedeltas, because `24H` is not valid for `%H`:

```
z = '31-12-2022:24'

a,b = z.split(':')

dt = pd.to_datetime(a, format='%d-%m-%Y') + pd.to_timedelta(int(b), unit='H')
print (dt)
2023-01-01 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with your date value, as there is no such hour as 24.
If your string will be correct, as e.g.:
'31-12-2022:12' it should be ok.